# MVC.net Date format in chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date

Im building my first application but now im currently stuck on the way that Chrome handles dates (in combination with IE).

I have a model with a field:

```
[Display(Name = "AcceptanceDate", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.ModelResources))]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
        public DateTime? AcceptanceDate { get; set; }
```

Im using this field in a view.

```
     @if (Request.UserAgent.ToLower().IndexOf("chrome") > -1)
                            {
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.AcceptanceDate, ViewBag.disableControls == true ? (object)new { disabled = "disabled", @class = "form-control" } : new { @class = "form-control", @type = "date" })
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.AcceptanceDate, ViewBag.disableControls == true ? (object)new { disabled = "disabled", @class = "form-control", @Value = Model.AcceptanceDate.HasValue ? Model.AcceptanceDate.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") : null } : new { @class = "form-control", @type = "date", @Value = Model.AcceptanceDate.HasValue ? Model.AcceptanceDate.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") : null })
                            }
```

And put a datepicker on the field with the following code:

```
<!-- jQueryUI Stylesheet (from CDN) -->
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $.datepicker.regional['nl'] = {
        monthNames: [
            'Januari', 'Februari', 'Maart', 'April', 'Mei', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'Augustus', 'September', 'Oktober',
            'November', 'December'
        ],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mei', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        dayNames: ['Maandag', 'Dinsdag', 'Woensdag', 'Donderdag', 'Vrijdag', 'Zaterdag', 'Zondag'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Ma', 'Di', 'Wo', 'Do', 'Vr', 'Za', 'Zo'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Ma', 'Di', 'Wo', 'Do', 'Vr', 'Za', 'Zo']
    }

    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['nl']);
    $(function () {
        $("input[type='date']").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            showButtonPanel: false
        }).attr('type', 'text');
    });
</script>
```

The dateformat is set to dd-MM-yyyy. When i call the view in Internet Explorer, everything works great. The value is retrieved from the database and is shown as expected (DD-MM-YYYY), the datepicker is working like a charm (the selected date is also shown as DD-MM-YYYY) and saving the data also works.

But when i use chrome the initial fieldvalue (when the view is loaded) is shown as YYYY-MM-DD. The datepicker does work and also after selecting a different date the date is being selected as DD-MM-YYYY.

Can somebody please tell me why chrome shows the initial value as YYYY-MM-DD??
I tried changing the code for the EditorFor in the view to the following code:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.AcceptanceDate, ViewBag.disableControls == true ? (object)new { disabled = "disabled", @class = "form-control", @Value = Model.AcceptanceDate.HasValue ? Model.AcceptanceDate.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") : null } : new { @class = "form-control", @type = "date", @Value = Model.AcceptanceDate.HasValue ? Model.AcceptanceDate.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") : null })
```

But this resulted in no value that was shown in the textboxes. (the value was send to the view but didnt show in the controls.

Please avise.

Comment: Please update your post to include the HTML fragment that is being generated (View Source from your web browser).

Comment: Your view code is not making a lot of sense. First, under no circumstance do you ever set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods. Second, the fact you have `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` means the `type="date"` is added automatically by the `EditorFor()` method. Third, why are you adding `type="date"` if you are using a jquery datepicker?

Comment: thanks Stephen, i just cleaned my code a bit (it was so messy because of older and newer code) and now it works like a charm both under IE and Chrome.